# ArgumentNullException in CreateDirectConversation/CreateDirectConversationAsync Bot Framework 4

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm migrating a bot from MS Botframework 3 to 4. We had a function that would email various individuals daily. Moving the code to v4 appears valid, but the call returns an error from inside the framework.

The exception is thrown in the `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication` namespace, in the method `MicrosoftAppCredentials(string appId, string password, HttpClient customHttpClient)`. The error is `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: clientId'`. customHttpClient inside that method is null. I do not see a way to pass along an HttpClient. Maybe my implementation is wrong?

My code:

```
ChannelAccount userAccount = new ChannelAccount(_config.UncategorizedReportToEmail, _config.UncategorizedReportToEmail);
var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(_config.BotEmail, _config.BotEmail);
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(_config.EmailServiceUrl));
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(_config.EmailServiceUrl);
// Next line is where the exception is thrown
var conversation = connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversation(botAccount, userAccount);
var conversationId = conversation.Id;
```

Comment: What happens if you put everything in explicitly instead of through _config?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes Thanks for the response. Putting explicit values in results in the same issue.

Comment: What happens if you change 'CreateDirectConversation' with 'CreateDirectConversationAsync'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: clientId'
```

This error is a result of appID/password not being read properly from the configuration file. Whether you're using a .bot file, a appsettings.json file, or a web.config file, please make sure your appID and password are correct.